# Execute procedure executing same statement twice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written this procedure,

```
DECLARE CURS_TABLE CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE 'AK_LIB_ADDRESS'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(300);
OPEN CURS_TABLE
FETCH NEXT FROM CURS_TABLE INTO @TABLE_NAME;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+@TABLE_NAME+' ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);';
  EXEC (@SQL)
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURS_TABLE INTO @TABLE_NAME
END

CLOSE CURS_TABLE;
DEALLOCATE CURS_TABLE;
```

The problem is the exec(@sql) executing the same statement twice, i checked by placing print statement,it's working fine with print statement if i comment exec line...
So please can u give me any idea where i'm doing wrong..?

Comment: can be that you have duplicate table names in that table?? :D

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this, used a temporary table instead of selecting directly from the sys.tables

```
SELECT NAME into #temp FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE 'AK_LIB_ADDRESS%'
DECLARE CURS_TABLE CURSOR FOR 
SELECT NAME from #temp 

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(300);
OPEN CURS_TABLE
FETCH NEXT FROM CURS_TABLE INTO @TABLE_NAME;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    select  @TABLE_NAME
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+@TABLE_NAME+' ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);';
    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURS_TABLE INTO @TABLE_NAME
END

CLOSE CURS_TABLE;
DEALLOCATE CURS_TABLE;
```

Or add a Insensitive keyword to the cursor. The reason is that you are changing a heap to the B-tree inside the trigger, that's the reason you are getting inconsistent behaviour in the cursor.

```
DECLARE CURS_TABLE CURSOR INSENSITIVE FOR 
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE 'AK_LIB_ADDRESS%'
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(300);
```

Comment: Hi Satheesh,thanks for quick reply, but i don't want this. Exactly, i want to add primary key to all those tables id column which name starting from the given string like 'lib_','lib_1'. but the problem is exec(@sql) executing the alter statement twice when i'm using "ALTER TABLE AK_LIB_ADDRESS ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID)", and because of this i'm getting error
Error Table 'AK_LIB_ADDRESS' already has a primary key defined on it. so please help me..

Comment: Hi Krishna, I just updated the code, using a temp table and it works fine. I do not know why this weird behaviour though

Comment: Hi Satheesh, yes, it is working as expected.thank you so much to you for helping me...